# Cloud build android - Manifest not found error

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am using Google Cloud to build a simple Android Project.

I have been using the docker image and following the instructions from the repo:
[Cloud Build Android](https://github.com/syslogic/cloudbuild-android)

As per the instructions mentioned in the repo, my repository does contains the generated image: cloudbuild-android

[image]

The cloudbuild.yml file also mentions something like below of which I do not have any clue:

> 'eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/cloudbuild'

Due to this, my build fails with the following error:

```
Step #0 - "docker-pull": Digest: 
sha256:231bb3e5638201d7c4e3db000512045b520be1fb368382979ce9e3c858876a3d

Step #0 - "docker-pull": Status: Downloaded newer image for eu.gcr.io/test-android- 
cloud-build/cloudbuild-android:8e70f56

Step #0 - "docker-pull": eu.gcr.io/test-android-cloud-build/cloudbuild- 
android:8e70f56

Finished Step #0 - "docker-pull"
Starting Step #1 - "gradle-build"
Step #1 - "gradle-build": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud- 
builders/docker

Step #1 - "gradle-build": Unable to find image 'eu.gcr.io/test-android-cloud- 
build/cloudbuild:latest' locally
Step #1 - "gradle-build": docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for 
eu.gcr.io/test-android-cloud-build/cloudbuild:latest not found: manifest unknown: 
Failed to fetch "latest" from request "/v2/test-android-cloud- 
build/cloudbuild/manifests/latest".

Step #1 - "gradle-build": See 'docker run --help'.
Finished Step #1 - "gradle-build"
```

Below is the yaml file:

```
# cloudbuild.yaml

steps:

- name: eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/cloudbuild-android:8e70f56
   id: 'docker-pull'
   args: ['cp', '-a', '.', '/persistent_volume']
   volumes:
- name: data
  path: /persistent_volume

- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  id: 'gradle-build'
  volumes:
- name: data
   path: /persistent_volume
   args: ['run', '-v', 'data:/workspace', '--rm', 
    'eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/cloudbuild', '/bin/sh', '-c', 'cd 
    /workspace && ./gradlew mobile:assembleDebug && mv 
    mobile/build/outputs/apk/debug/mobile-debug.apk 
    mobile/build/outputs/apk/debug/$REPO_NAME-$SHORT_SHA- 
    debug.apk && ls -la 
    mobile/build/outputs/apk/debug/$REPO_NAME-$SHORT_SHA- 
    debug.apk']

- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
  id: 'publish-gsutil'
  args: ['cp',   
   '/persistent_volume/mobile/build/outputs/apk/
    debug/$REPO_NAME-$SHORT_SHA-debug.apk', 
    'gs://eu.artifacts.$PROJECT_ID.appspot.com/android/']
  volumes:
 - name: data
  path: /persistent_volume

 timeout: 1200s
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you add docker and yaml file.And this line `eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT\_ID/cloudbuild` in configuration file is the reference to the Docker image,`eu.gcr.io` is the domain for the  container registry in the European Union (EU) region, project id and  name of the Docker image

Comment: @SathiAiswarya Hi, I have added the yaml file. I am not sure about the docker file maybe it is missing, I just followed the instructions on the page. The first line says "It builds a Docker container from Google Cloud Source Repositories ", is this what I am missing?

Comment: check the docker image reference is correct.make sure the image exists in your container registry.